# Is it safe to use memcpy like this?

Tags: c, memcpy, review

```
memcpy(buf, buf + (pos - offset), len);
```

whereas,

```
0<=pos<=strlen(buf), 0<=offset<=strlen(buf)
```

Is it safe to use `memcpy()` in this scenario? If not, what could go wrong? Please suggest the best practice.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy): *"If the objects overlap (which is a violation of the `restrict` contract) (since C99), the behavior is undefined"*

Comment: You can read manual for `memcpy` before asking here.

Comment: Even using `memmove` as advised, with the limits you specify `pos - offset` can be `< 0`.

Comment: What are the types of `pos`, `offset`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it isn't. Use [`memmove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) instead.

If the memory zones overlap when using `memcpy`, the behaviour is undefined. Though it *may* appear to work depending on the implementation.

References:

- [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dswaw1wk.aspx)
- [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy)
- [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)
- [Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html)

Answer (score 2):

Since C99, memcpy has the following declaration

```
void* memcpy(void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t count);
```

The `restrict` is a keyword that tells the compiler that the object of the pointer will only be accessed through the pointer itself. Essentially that means that the compiler (and the implementor of `memcpy`) can assume the two regions do not overlap.

So for example, if `memcpy` is implemented by a simple iteration copying bytes from the beginning, everything will be fine, as long as the regions do not overlap, and in fact it will be fine if the source region is above the destination region. However, if the regions overlap and the source region is at lower addresses than the destination region, the end of the source region will be clobbered by the copy before it is copied. This is possible in your case if `pos - offset < 0` and `offset - pos < len`

You also can't assume that is the only possibility for error, some computer architectures have instructions that might make it quicker to start copying from the top and work downwards in which case `memcpy` is safe when the source is below the destination and overlapping, but not above the destination and overlapping. This would be true in your case if `len > pos - offset`

So with any possibility of overlap, always use `memmove`. You are however safe if `len <= pos - offset` because your two regions are guaranteed not to overlap.